# How to calculate the (proper) transformation matrix between two frames (axial systems) in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, transform

For a project in Unity3D I'm trying to transform all objects in the world by changing frames. What this means is that the origin of the new frame is rotated, translated, and scaled to match the origin of the old frame, then this operation is applied to all other objects (including the old origin).
For this, I need a generalized, 3-dimensional (thus 4x4) Transformation-Matrix.

I have looked at using Unity's built-in Matrix4x4.TRS()-method, but this seems useless, as it only applies the Translation, Rotation & Scale to a defined point.
What I'm looking for, is a change of frames, in which the new frame has a different origin, rotation, AND scale, with regards to the original one.

To visualize the problem, I've made a small GIF (I currently have a working version in 3D, without using a Matrix, and without any rotation):
https://gyazo.com/8a7ab04dfef2c96f53015084eefbdb01

The values for each sphere:

```
Origin1 (Red Sphere)

Before:   
Position (-10, 0, 0)
Rotation (0,0,0)
Scale    (4,4,4)   

After:
Position (10, 0, 0)
Rotation (0,0,0)
Scale    (8,8,8)   

-
Origin2 (Blue Sphere)

Before:   
Position (-20, 0, 0)
Rotation (0,0,0)
Scale    (2,2,2)   

After:
Position (-10, 0, 0)
Rotation (0,0,0)
Scale    (4,4,4)   

-
World-Object (White Sphere)

Before:   
Position (0, 0, 10)
Rotation (0,0,0)
Scale    (2,2,2)   

After:
Position (30, 0, 20)
Rotation (0,0,0)
Scale    (4,4,4)
```

Currently I'm simply taking the Vector between the 2 origins, scaling that to the difference between the two origins, then applying that on top of the new position of the original (first) origin.
This will of course not work when rotation is applied to any of the 2 origins.

```
// Position in original axes
Vector3 positionBefore = testPosition.TestPosition - origin.TestPosition;
// Position in new axes
Vector3 positionAfter = (positionBefore * scaleFactor) + origin.transform.position;
```

What I'm looking for is a Matrix that can do this (and include rotation, such that Origin2 is rotated to the rotation Origin1 was in before the transformation, and all other objects are moved to their correct positions).

Is there a way to do this without doing the full calculation on every Vector (i.e. transforming the positionbefore-Vector)? It needs to be applied to a (very) large number of objects every frame, thus it needs to be (fairly) optimized.

Edit: Scaling will ALWAYS be uniform.

Comment: I didn't completely understand .. but you know that you have to change only one parent object of  you attach everything else as child to it in the hierarchy?

Comment: There is no parent-child relation here.
In fact, in the final result, there aren't even gameobjects, just Data (entities)

Comment: Nevermind..
Had to apply the rotation & scale to the Translation before creating the TRS
D'Oh

Answer (score 1):

There might be other solutions but here is what I would do

1. Wrap your objects into the following hierarchy

   ```
   WorldAnchorObject
   |- Red Sphere
   |- Blue Sphere
   |- White Sphere
   ```
2. Make sure the `WorldAnchorObject` has

   ```
   position: 0,0,0
   rotation: 0,0,0
   localScale: 1,1,1
   ```
3. position/rotate/scale the Spheres (this will now happen relative to `WorldAnchorObject`)
4. Now all that is left is to transform the `WorldAnchorObject` -> it will move, scale and rotate anything else and keeps the relative transforms intact.

   How exactly you move the world anchor is your thing. I guess you want to allways center and normalize a certain child object. Maybe something like

   ```
   public void CenterOnObject(GameObject targetCenter)
   {
       var targetTransform = targetCenter.transform;
       // The localPosition and localRotation are relative to the parent
       var targetPos = transform.localPosition;
       var targetRot = targetTransform.localRotation;
       var targetScale = targetTransform.localScale;

       // First reset everything
       transform.position = Vector3.zero;
       transform.rotation = Quaternion.Idendity;
       transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

       // set yourself to inverted target position
       // After this action the target should be on 0,0,0
       transform.position = targetPos * -1;
       // Scale yourself relative to 0,0,0
       var newScale = Vector3.one * 1/targetScale.x;
       ScaleAround(gameObject, Vector3.zero, newScale);
       // Now everything should be scaled so that the target 
       // has scale 1,1,1 and still is on position 0,0,0

       // Now rotate around 0,0,0 so that the rotation of the target gets normalized
       transform.rotation = Quaternion.Inverse(targetRotation);
   }

   // This scales an object around a certain pivot and 
   // takes care of the correct position translation as well
   private void ScaleAround(GameObject target, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 newScale)
   {
       Vector3 A = target.transform.localPosition;
       Vector3 B = pivot;

       Vector3 C = A - B; // diff from object pivot to desired pivot/origin

       float RS = newScale.x / target.transform.localScale.x; // relative scale factor

       // calc final position post-scale
       Vector3 FP = B + C * RS;

       // finally, actually perform the scale/translation
       target.transform.localScale = newScale;
       target.transform.localPosition = FP;
   }
   ```

   Now you call it passing one of the children like e.g.

   ```
   worldAnchorReference.CenterOnObject(RedSphere);
   ```

   should result in what you wanted to achieve. (Hacking this in on my smartphone so no warranties but if there is trouble I can check it as soon as I'm with a PC again. ;))

Comment: Can't use a hierarchy. This is a math-problem, not a Unity-Transform-problem.
ECS (https://unity.com/unity/features/job-system-ECS) doesn't even have Transforms